# Tls connection not showing messages

Tags: ssl, mqtt, tls1.2, mosquitto

I am trying to establish a ssl pipeline in MQTT broker. For broker I am using vernemq and client mosquito clients.

When I try to publish or subscribe I am getting the following message.

```
Client mosqsub/29373-ip-172-31 sending CONNECT
Client mosqpub/29376-ip-172-31 sending CONNECT
```

It showing sending connect after that It doesn't show anything. The message also not received.This is the exact command I used.

```
mosquitto_pub --cafile ca.crt --cert client.crt --key client.key -h 172.31.45.91  -p 1883 -t foo -q 1 -m test1  -d

mosquitto_sub --cafile ca.crt --cert client.crt --key client.key -h 172.31.45.91 -p 1883 -t foo -d
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Note I am running on AWS.

Answer (score 1):

If you are only seeing:

```
Client mosqsub/29373-ip-172-31 sending CONNECT
```

and nothing else it implies that the client is is waiting for a response from the broker. A full connect set of debug messages should look something like this:

```
Client mosqsub/26111-tiefighte sending CONNECT
Client mosqsub/26111-tiefighte received CONNACK
Client mosqsub/26111-tiefighte sending SUBSCRIBE (Mid: 1, Topic: #, QoS: 0)
Client mosqsub/26111-tiefighte received SUBACK
Subscribed (mid: 1): 0
```

The most usual reason for what you are seeing is probably that you have not opened the required ports on the machine running the broker so the firewall is just dropping packets and the client is waiting for the TCP timeout (15mins) before failing to connect.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like it is hanging on ssl handshake phase in ssl-connection setup process.

To figure out is it reason or not need to verify ssl-connectivity:

> openssl s_client -connect **host:port** -CAfile **ca cert file** -nbio
>   -debug -msg -state -cert **cert** -key **secret key**

most probably it is stucked on some step of this process.
If you see that SSL-session successfully setup then need to check trace
on broker side